# Stochastic process simulation, periodogram implementation, MATLAB, frequecy range

Tags: stochastic-processes, fourier-analysis, matlab, fourier-transform, simulation

I have to implement from scratch on MATLAB the periodogram of a very simple stochastic process:

$$X(t)=A_1\cos(2\pi f_1t+\phi_1)+A_2\cos(2\pi f_2t+\phi_2)$$

where $f_1=5$, $f_2=10$, $A_1,A_2\sim Rayleigh(\sigma^2)$, $\sigma^2=2$ and $\phi_1,\phi_2\sim U[0,2\pi]$.

To simulate it, I built a function that takes as inputs the frequencies $f_1,f_2,\sigma^2$, and allows for the user to define how many cycles of the periodic process they want to see, and how many data points. As this is a sum of two cosines, the fundamental frequency is $\min\{f_1,f_2\}$.

Therefore, my time vector is created as `time=linspace(0,cycles/fundamental,datapoints)'`.

I should then create a function that implements the periodogram of this stochastic process. It mainly consists of two steps:

Fourier transform of the data:

$$\mathcal{X}(f)=\sum_{t=0}^{n-1}x(t)e^{-2\pi ft}$$

Periodogram, as follows:

$$\hat{R}_x(f)=\frac{1}{n}|\mathcal{X}(f)|^2$$

I can say that my stochastic process was sampled with period `Ts=(cycles/fundamental)/datapoints`.

If I did everything right so far, my big doubt is: **how should I define the frequency range?**

On MATLAB's reference for FFT, the frequency range is: `Fs*(0:datapoints/2)/datapoints`, which seems reasonable, but in my case, if I do that, I may cause my spectrum "spikes" to occur not exactly at $f_1$ and $f_2$ unless my `datapoints` get very high.

On the other hand, pushing my `datapoints` to a large number causes my spectrum to show a huge range of frequencies that carry no relevant information at all, since my process is composed only by two low frequency cosines.

I believe that once I get this frequency range issue solved, the rest is straightforward:

```
w=-1i*2*pi*freq;

wt=w.*t;

W=exp(wt);

X_f=x'*W;

R_f=(1/(length(x)).*abs(X_f).^2;
```

Hope you guys can enlighten me with this issue.

By the way, the reference I am using is Georg Lindgren's *Stationary stochastic Processes for Scientists and Engineers*